# Repeating nock responses indefinitely

Tags: javascript, node.js, nock

The mocking framework Nock.js removes responses after answering them. There is a feature to repeat a response n times, but is there something I can do if I want it to respond to a certain request with the same response every time it is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nock(url).get(path).times(Infinity)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use persist() method

```
nock(url).get(path).persist()
```